# How to deliver text or binary data to the browser in an ASP.NET Core Razor pages project

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

Using the code below, I would expect to just display the string `abcdefg` in the user's browser. Instead, the user gets the following JSON in their browser when visiting this page:

`{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["text/plain"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Pages
{
    [Route("api/Mvc")]
    public class MvcController : Controller
    {
        //public IActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int imageid)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent("abcdefg");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

            return Task.FromResult(response);

        }
    }
}
```

I am new to this platform and fundamentally misunderstanding something but my searches have been fruitless.

Ultimately the purpose of this code is to change the mime type to `image/jpeg` and use a `StreamContent` to deliver binary data (a jpeg image stored inside a database).

Answer (score 0):

Found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

For text:

```
    public ActionResult Get(int imageid)
    {
        return Content("abcdefg");
    }
```

For binary:

```
    public ActionResult Get(int imageid)
    {
        byte[] data = GetData(imageid);
        return File(data, "image/jpeg");
    }
```